# A question about small sets of reals

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, measure-theory

In ZFC, does there exist an uncountable set of reals $A$ such that for every closed measure zero set of reals $B$, we have that $ A + B = \{a+b : a \in A, b \in B\} \neq \mathbb{R}$?

This question is motivated from the results in the following [paper](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1981-28.pdf).

Note that under CH, there are such sets (Lusin/Sierpinski sets) and a model where every such set is countable must satisfy the Borel and the dual-Borel conjecture.

The fact that Sierpinski sets are strongly meager is due to Pawlikowsi. A more general result appears in Pawlikowski, Strongly meager sets and subsets of plane, Fundamenta Math., 156, 1998. Lusin sets are strongly null because for any sequence $\langle \epsilon_n : n \geq 1 \rangle$, the set $\bigcup \{(r_n - \epsilon_{2n}, r_n + \epsilon_{2n}) : n \geq 1\}$  , where $r_n$'s run over all rationals, covers all but countably many points in the Lusin set. Finally, if there is no uncountable set $A$ as above, then there cannot be any uncountable strongly meager/null set because if $A$ is uncountable strongly meager/null set then $A + B \neq \mathbb{R}$ for any $B$ which is both meager and null.

Comment: To complement the question, the recent paper by Goldstern, Kellner, Shelah, Wohofsky establishing the relative consistency of BC+dBC is [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2014-366-01/S0002-9947-2013-05783-2/home.html) and [on the arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.0823). Also, Goldstern's overview of the proof is [on the arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.4424/).

Comment: Could you add proofs to your notes?

Comment: I added some explanations and one reference.

Comment: Could you point out some more implications among your property and more well-studied ones (e.g., selection principles)?

Comment: Did you consider a union of a [$\mathfrak{b}$-scale](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.5645) (a ZFC object) and the rationals? That's the candidate I would try first. It is SMZ if, e.g., $\mathfrak{b}\le \text{cov}(\mathcal{M})$. It is perfectly meager, though I guess it is not necessarily strongly meager. But you seek for weaker properties, don't you?